# C++ correct syntax for triple-nested template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm confused why the below code gets rejected by the compiler. Some help please?

```
template<template<template<class> class> class Ptr,
template<class> class Container, class T>
inline void print(Ptr<Container<T>> l) {
    std::cout << '[';
    for (auto it = l->begin(); it != l->end() - 1; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << l->back() << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Where did I use it as a variable name?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant then what is the fix?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant There's nothing wrong with `template<class> class`. That's an unnamed template template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got confused of what works and what not in @RSahu answer and whether it solves the problem in general.

But, *inspired by it*, I get the following solution. Which simply exploits the fact that the class template class can be variadic. So for example is now compatible with `std::vector<T, A>` or other classes (containers hopefuly) that have more or less template parameters. In fact it is useful to do the same with the `Ptr` parameter so it is also compatible with `std::unique_ptr` that takes more template parameters than `std::shared_ptr`.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40d43526ed77eb9d

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<template<class...> class Ptr, template<class...> class Container, class T>
inline void f(Ptr<Container<T>> p) {
    std::cout << "bla" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>());
}
```

---

Note: having said that, I think there are better ways to constrain the argument types than forcing patterns.

For example, this could be an alternative:

```
template<class PtrContainerT, typename = decltype( std::declval<PtrContainerT>()->back())> //probably pretty much constrains the intended use
inline void f(PtrContainerT&& p) {
    using T = typename PtrContainerT::element_type::value_type; //in case you need to know T
    std::cout << "bla" << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbe43aab94364764

or even more to the point (although not 100% equivalent) :

```
template<class PtrContainerT, typename T = typename PtrContainerT::element_type::value_type> //probably pretty much constrains the intended use
inline void f(PtrContainerT&& p) {
    std::cout << "bla" << std::endl;
}
```

Use `std::decay<PtrContainerT>::...etc` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following two ways to resolve the problem.

```
template <template <template <class> class> class Ptr,
          template<class> class Container, class T>
inline void print(Ptr<Container> l) {
                // ^^^ Not Ptr<Container<T>>
    std::cout << '[';
    for (auto it = l->begin(); it != l->end() - 1; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << l->back() << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
template <template<class> class Ptr,
         // One less level of template for Ptr
          template<class> class Container, class T>
inline void print(Ptr<Container<T>> l) {
               // Containe<T> is a class
    std::cout << '[';
    for (auto it = l->begin(); it != l->end() - 1; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << l->back() << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

Looking at your code, it not clear which one will work for you.

**Update**

The following code does not work

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<template<class> class Ptr, template<class> class Container, class T>
inline void f(Ptr<Container<T>> p) {}

int main() {
    f(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>());
}
```

since `std::vector` is defined as:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

It is not

```
template<
    class T,
> class vector;
```

This works:

```
template<template<class> class Ptr, template<class> class Container, class T>
inline void f(Ptr<Container<T>> p) {}

template <typename T> using MyVector = std::vector<T>;

int main() {
    f<std::shared_ptr, MyVector, int>(std::make_shared<MyVector<int>>());
}
```

This also works:

```
template<template<class> class Ptr, template<class> class Container, class T>
inline void f(Ptr<Container<T>> p) {}

template <typename T> struct Foo {};

int main() {
    f(std::make_shared<Foo<int>>());
}
```

Comment: The `T` parameter is not used in this example, but I do need it. I'm trying to pass a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>` as the argument for example.

Comment: I get the following error message `note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure
      [with Ptr = shared_ptr]: template template argument has different template
      parameters than its corresponding template template parameter`

Comment: @xiver77, in that case, you can use the second solution.